# Stack Panel in Silverlight 5

Tags: .net, xaml, silverlight-5.0

Can any one please tell me how to create stackPanels in .cs coding? I need to create multiple stack panels by coding. Can any one pls help regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a container in your main page to your stackpanels.

**Xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White" Width="500" Height="500">

</Grid>
```

**Code**

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel(); 
sp.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal; 
//add something in your stack panel
LayoutRoot.Children.Add(sp);
```

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for your response. 

Actually i am creating creating dynamic user controls. I need to add two sets of radio button. Each set has two radio buttons. while adding all the four buttons under single stack panel i can able to select any 1 among four radio buttons. But i need to select two radio buttons. So i need to create two stack panels. Could you pls tell me how to create two stack panel in code?

And also i need to create stack panel as per user's input..

Could you pls share your idea?

Comment: so what is your question ?

Comment: Hi,

      I need to add stack panels dynamically in xaml.cs file?

If we need to create single stack panel then we can do it by

StackPanel st = new StackPanel()

But if we want to create for 10 times or n times then how can we do that?

Could you pls suggest anything ?

Comment: You should add more detail and some of your code to clarify your original question.

Comment: ok
if you create a two sets of buttons in a code you can select any one from that four buttons. can you agree with this?\